# How to remove comments from a given String in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace, comments

how do I remove comments start with "//" and with /**, * etc.? I haven't found any solutions on Stack Overflow that has helped me very much, a lot of them have been way above my head and I'm still at most basics.

What I have thought about so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  for (j = i; j < length; j++) {
        if (obj.charAt(j) == '/' && obj.charAt(j + 1) == '/')
```

But I'm not really sure how to replace the words following those characters. And how to end when to stop the replacement with a "//" comment. With the /* comments, atleast conceptually I know I should replace all words till "*/" pops up. Though again, I'm not sure how to limit the replacement till that point. To replace I thought replacing the charAt after the second "/" with an empty string until....where? I cannot figure out where to "end" the replacing.

I have looked at a few implementations on Stack, but I really didn't get it. Any help is appreciated, especially if it's at a basic level and understandable for someone not well versed in programming!

Thanks.

Comment: Since // are considered one line comments you could just delete the entire line when you encounter // - probably easier said then done. Are you reading your data from a fileReader?

Comment: It's not a "replace" kind of deal, you need to iterate original string and only correct non-comment chars into the output. It's a simple parser with state machine having 3 states: active text, "//"-comment, and "/*"-comment. Second state is limited till end of line character in your current encoding.

Comment: Just a String, I have no given String as such, there are test cases that will put up multiple sorts of strings with comments etc. to test if they get removed. And I'm not sure how I'm supposed to "delete" a whole line if I encounter //. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Roni Strings have linebreaks....

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar with regex **(Java 9+)**:

```java
// Checks for
// 1) Single char literal '"'
// 2) Single char literal '\"'
// 3) Strings; termination ignores \", \\\", ..., but allows ", \\", \\\\", ...
// 4) Single-line comment // ... to first \n
// 5) Multi-line comments /*[*] ... */
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "(?s)('\"'|'\\\"'|\".*?(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*\"|//[^\n]*|/\\*.*?\\*/)");

// Assuming 'text' contains your java text
// Leaves 1,2,3) unchanged and replaces comments 4,5) with ""
// Need quoteReplacement to prevent matcher processing $ and \
String textWithoutComments = regex.matcher(text).replaceAll(
    m -> m.group().charAt(0) == '/' ? "" : Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group()));
```

If you don't have Java 9+ then you could use this replace function:

```java
String textWithoutComments = replaceAll(regex, text,
    m -> m.group().charAt(0) == '/' ? "" : m.group());
```

```java
public static String replaceAll(Pattern p, String s,
    Function<MatchResult, String> replacer) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    int lastStart = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        String replacement = replacer.apply(m);
        b.append(s.substring(lastStart, m.start())).append(replacement);
        lastStart = m.end();
    }
    return b.append(s.substring(lastStart)).toString();
}
```

Comment: Woah, I really don't get the regex expression at all, I've never seen that before. Where are you getting the Pattern class from, I don't think I have looked at stuff like that yet. It is an assignment in a first sem class, so i don't think it needs a solution as complicated as this. I understand your substring class, but totally lost at the Pattern, Matcher and Function classes. Is there a more simple way you could guide me through, or atleast pseudo code types with ways I might know with basic knowledge? Thanks for the ideas, though!

Comment: No problem - regular expressions are a powerful way to search and extract text, you will probably learn it in a later class. `Pattern, Matcher, MatchResult` are under `java.util.regex`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Without going into the fine detail of the pattern, primarily it looks for comments /*..*/ and //. To prevent matching within a string, the string pattern is added. When the string pattern matches, its contents won't be matched for comments. Then because a char quote literal '"' would match the string start pattern, this is also added to avoid a false string match.

Comment: The matcher is the class that scans text to find pattern matches. Its `replaceAll` method provides a callback for every match it finds. The function that receives the callback returns what it wants the matched text to be replaced with. So for comments (starts with `/` for `//` and `/*..*/`) it returns empty string. The other matches return the same text that was matched (effectively no replacement). It needs `quoteReplacement` as the method treats `$` and `\\` as special characters, and we want them left alone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse but you could do this without using code if you're just interested in removing all comments for the project. You can do this with "Replace in Path" tool. Notice how "Regex" is checked, allowing us to match lines based on regular expressions.

[image]

This configuration in the tool will delete all lines starting with a `//` and replace it with an empty line.

The command to get to this on a Mac is `ctrl + shift + r`.